# Finding $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{d_3}+...+\frac{1}{d_k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

If we assume that $d_1,d_2,d_3,...,d_k$ are the  divisors for the positive integer $n$ except $1,n$ if $d_1+d_2+d_3+...+ d_k=72$ then how to find $$\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{d_3}+...+\frac{1}{d_k}$$

Comment: what are you trying ?

Comment: $1$ is not prime. I'm sure you meant all divisors

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused - do you want all the divisors, or all the prime divisors? Excluding $1$ causes the confusion, but the problem is actually easier when you are using all the divisors other than $1,n$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show that $\sum\nolimits\_{d|n} \frac{1}{d} = \frac{\sigma (n)}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157419/show-that-sum-nolimits-dn-frac1d-frac-sigma-nn-for-every-pos)

Comment: @Norbert Well, he is only looking at primes $d_i$, at least so far. Even if the problem is about all divisors, this is a more specific problem - In that case, OP is essentially asking for what $n$ is $\sigma(n)=73+n$.

Comment: I am surprised that this question has been closed as what used to be called a duplicate. True, a solution (**if the reference to primes is a mistake**) mostly uses similar *ideas* as the linked to post. But if one's criterion for duplicate is this broad, a large proportion of the questions should be closed.

Comment: @Norbert i  did not mean to say prime ..i edited the question .

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok, if you need exact isomorphism [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284525/find-the-value-of-frac1d-1-frac1d-2-dots-frac1d-k?rq=1)

Comment: @AndréNicolas is this the correct way to do it ?http://store2.up-00.com/Nov12/E4K81804.jpg

Comment: Looks OK. Add in the $1$ and the $n$. We get that the sum of **all* the (positive) divisors is $72+1+n=73+n$. Divide by $n$. We get, in some order, the sum of the reciprocals of the divisors. This is $\frac{73}{n}+1$.

Comment: @Norbert: I agree that the one you point to is quite close, though "adding back" the missing $1$ and $n$ may not be completely obvious to an inexperienced person.

Answer (score 3):

If you write:
$$
\sum_{d \mid n} \frac{1}{d} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{n}{d}
  = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} d = \frac{72}{n}
$$
The *divisor sum* $\sum_{d \mid n} d = \sigma(n)$ is easily seen to satisfy $\sigma(n) \ge n + 1$ (those two are divisors always; they are the only ones if $n$ is prime, otherwise there are more). So you'd have to check up to $n = 71$.
To find out what $n$ is so that $\sigma(n) = 72$, a fast trip to http://oeis.org/A000203 shows that the full list is 30, 46, 51, 55, 71.

Comment: Great answer, +1.

Answer (score 0):

The divisor function satisfies the reflection formula, $$n^x\sigma_{-x}(n)=\sigma_{x}(n)$$

Since $$\sum_{d\mid n} d^x=\sum_{d\mid n} (n/d)^x$$

Comment: What does sense means? I haven't seen this before. Unless it is a typo then never mind.

Comment: @Arjang, typo for "since", I'll wager.